glm::angleAxis function equivalent in cglm on C?
i'm trying to make a camera on C with cglm by a tutorial that uses glm. it uses glm::angleAxis to get rotation quaternions from pitch and yaw. i was searching if cglm have equivalent to this function, but didn't find any. how can i reproduce it's behaviour with cglm?
the code looks like so
glm::quat pitchRotation = glm::angleAxis(pitch, glm::vec3 { 1.f, 0.f, 0.f });
glm::quat yawRotation = glm::angleAxis(yaw, glm::vec3 { 0.f, -1.f, 0.f });

return glm::toMat4(yawRotation) * glm::toMat4(pitchRotation);

any suggestions on how to translate it somehow without angleAxis?

I think this is what you're looking for.
